# Why the "Sign In with Google" button looks different in Safari and in Chrome?

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin, google-identity

I'm trying to use the Google Identity >  [Sign In With Google for Web](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview) on a test web application. I followed the [Display the Sign In With Google button](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button) and the button (and the One Tap) show the way I expected in Google Chrome

[image: sign in with google button in google chrome]

Note how the button shows my name and email address already

But in Safari I get a generic button:

[image: sign in with google button in Safari]

I'm able to login to my test app with Safari and Chrome, so it's not because it's my first login (which I noticed it's one reason why both Chrome and Safari will show a generic button)

I know that the button experience should be the same in Safari and Chrome because the "sign in with google" button in the documentation overview https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview looks right in both Safari and Chrome.

[image]
[image]

So what can prevent Safari from displaying my name and email in the button?

The button code:

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="<%=google_client_id%>"
     data-context="signin"
     data-ux_mode="redirect"
     data-login_uri="<%=login_uri%>"
     data-nonce=""
     data-itp_support="true">
</div>

<div class="g_id_signin"
     data-type="standard"
     data-shape="rectangular"
     data-theme="outline"
     data-text="signin_with"
     data-size="large"
     data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>
```

Comment: _"So what can prevent Safari from displaying my name and email in the button?"_ - Safari has more restrictive privacy protections than Chrome, it also implements different standards for certain cross-origin activities.

Comment: but the button looks right in Safari / Chrome in https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview . Do you mean it only looks ok because developers.google.com is not cross-origin with google.com?

Comment: Have you ever signed-in to `developers.google.com` in Safari before?

Comment: yes, I have, I also signed to my own test web app in both Safari and Chrome before.

Comment: More details about why Safari behaves different are here: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/supported-browsers - also, all browsers today enable or disable some relevant features relating to cross-origin activivty based on whether the user has "interacted" with the page prior to the cross-origin activity (this is to prevent hidden iframes doing things without the user knowing).

Comment: Also, your page is _always_ using `https://` (even for `localhost`), right?

Comment: yes, I'm using `https://localhost.mydomain.com` and valid  "let's encrypt" certificates for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button looks different in Safari because Safari blocks third party cookies by default "Preferences > Privacy > Website tracking > Prevent cross-site tracking". See  Apple Support > [Prevent cross-site tracking in Safari on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/safari/sfri40732/mac)

It seems that the ITP (Intelligent Tracking Protection) in Safari negates the "advanced" version of the "Sign in with Google" button.

In the Safari Privacy Report you can see that it blocked google.com

[image]

After disabling temporarily that option and reloading the page in Safari, the "Sign In with Google" button looks the same as in Chrome or Firefox.

[image]

Of course, the rest of the Safari users will have the "Prevent cross-site tracking" enabled so they will still see the other version of the button, unfortunately.

Comment: _"...unfortunately."_ - On the contrary, personally I consider it a positive feature of Safari, not an unfortunate problem. I'm sure many of your users will feel the same way.